# Share Google Drive Folder via Zapier with Mailchimp trigger

Tags: google-drive-api, mailchimp, zapier

I can't figure out how to format the "Custom Value for Sharing Preference" on this Zap I'm trying to create that will share a Google Drive folder with my new Mailchimp subscribers.

I've been able to get the File ID using the Drive API, but I'm not sure how to provide the Custom Value that should come from the New Mailchimp Subscriber Email.

[image]

If I simply choose the Email address from the Mailchimp dropdown provided by Zapier and test it, I get an error:

> We had trouble sending your test through. The app returned "The
>   permission type field is required.". This usually happens when your
>   Zap is missing a required field or a field value isn't in a recognized
>   format.

EDIT: Success via the Google Drive API test.

Using the [sandbox available here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create), I know that I need to:

`POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions`

the following Request Body

```
{
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "user",
  "emailAddress": "email@example.com"
}
```

I've been able to run that test a few times with Google's sandbox, so I know I can do it. I just don't know how to pull this into Zapier.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this? I'm working on some ideas now, but wanted to check and see if you solved it. Thanks!

Comment: I did not get this solved. Good luck to you if you're able and keep me posted! Happy to accept your answer if you sort it out and post here.

Comment: Thanks @Brian — it turns out that there isn't a way to do this using the standard Google Drive integration for Zapier. We ended up building a custom Google Drive integration for Zapier that makes this feature available. Feel free to hit me up if you'd be interested in testing it out!

Comment: Bummer ... glad you were able to build your integration, though! I'm all good now, don't need this any longer although I'll definitely hit you up if it comes back up. Thanks!