# How do I use Zapier to share permissions to a Google Drive file ID with a specific email address?

Tags: google-drive-api, zapier

This is practically the same question as [brianrhea’s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951067/share-google-drive-folder-via-zapier-with-mailchimp-trigger) from back in December.

The goal is to use Zapier to share file permissions with a specific email address.

[Here’s a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTJA8.png) to show you where I am in Zapier.

And yes, I’ve contacted Zapier support; just hoping someone here may have a helpful and timely answer. Thank you!

Comment: were you ever able to resolve this? I'm working on some ideas for this now, but wanted to see if you found a solution first. Thanks!